# Using beautifulSoup and python to find length of the maximum sequence of links in html?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

My task is to find body of article `<div id="bodyContent">` and inside it calculate the length of the maximum sequence of links between which there are no other tags that opened or closed. For example:

```
<p>
    <span><a></a></span>
    **<a></a>
    <a></a>**
</p>
```

- there are 2 links in a row, because closing span interrupts the sequence.

```
 <p>
    **<a><span></span></a>
    <a></a>
    <a></a>**
</p
```

- and there are 3 links of the sub-series, because span is inside the link, not between links.
To solve it I'm using beautifulsoup and python.

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone_Age')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")
body = soup.find(id="bodyContent")

# get first link
first_link = body.a

# find all links that are in the same level
first_link.find_next_siblings('a')
```

How to go to the following links?

Best Regards!

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone_Age')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")
body = soup.find(id="bodyContent")

tag = body.find_next("a")
linkslen = -1
while (tag):
    curlen = 1
    for tag in tag.find_next_siblings():
        if tag.name != 'a':
            break
        curlen += 1
    if curlen > linkslen:
         linkslen = curlen
     tag = tag.find_next("a")
 print(linkslen)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone_Age')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")
body = soup.find(id="bodyContent")
all_links = body.find_all('a')
sequence = 0
for link in all_links:
    len = 1
    for l in link.find_next_siblings():
        if l.name != 'a':
            break
        len += 1
    sequence = max(sequence, len)
print(sequence)
```